# Using Truth Table to conclude.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I have made this truth table for the following propositions.

> While scouting and investigating the flora of an island, biologists identified Three species of plants of particular interest: Dahlia, Crocus and Snowdrop. The biologists made the following observations:
>
> 1. If Dahlias grow in an area, Crocus will also grow in that area.
> 2. Either Crocus or Snowdrops grow in an area (i.e. but they never grow together in that area).
> 3. Dahlias or Snowdrops always grow in an area.
>
> I Convert aforementioned observations into propositional formula. I Relying on a truth table, identify which plants can grow in the different areas of the Island (i.e: which plants of interest can you find in an area of the Island?)

[image]

**The question is asking**

> Relying on a truth table, identify which plants can grow in the different areas of the Island (i.e: which plants of interest can you find in an area of the Island?)

I don't understand how I can use the table to see which plants can grow in the different areas of the island. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As commented before: "better to use mathjax instead of images"

Comment: 1,2,3 are premises to be "modelled" with prop symbols. Example for 1: if D then C.

Comment: The truth table will tell you which combinations of flowers can be found growing together.

Comment: You have to check, what conclusions follows from said premises (using truth table as a way to prove tautological consequence).

Comment: The possible conclusions are: C=Crocus will grow in that area, and so on.

Comment: For the time being, forget about truth tables; you need to translate the given premises into symbolic *compound* propositions (for example, $P{\implies}Q$ and $P\land Q$; whereas $P$ and $Q$ are *atomic* propositions); start by symbolising, using the above suggestions, the atomic propositions within the premises. After you've done these, the next step will feel less abstract and become more concrete. Welcome to this site!

Comment: @ryang I disagree.  Without realizing it, the OP (i.e. orginal poster) has *virtually* solved the problem.  It is simply a matter of understanding how to *use* the truth-table.

Answer (score 0):

Without realizing it, you have solved the problem.

The whole point of the truth table approach is that only those rows where the computed values are all **True** are acceptable.  These rows represent the rows where all of the constraints are satisfied.

You have **already** determined this.

Your rightmost computed column shows that only rows $2$ and $7$ satisfy the constraints.

These represent the following possibilities:

- Dahlia, Crocus, and not Snowdrop
- Snowdrop only.